# How do I setup AWS Data Pipeline to copy on-premise Hive data to S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

I read through the documentation, which talks about MySQL and RDS. But could not find anything on moving on premise Hive/Hadoop data to S3. I appreciate any links or articles.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [S3DistCp](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/UsingEMR_s3distcp.html) to copy HDFS data from your on-premise to S3 and vise versa.

Comment: Are you referring to topic _To copy data from your Hadoop cluster to Amazon S3 using S3DistCp_ in the document **Amazon Web Services – Best Practices for Amazon EMR**? How can I setup these steps as part of AWS Data Pieline?

Comment: I was refering to running shell command activity in data pipeline  copying  data by using s3distcp http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-shellcommandactivity.html

Answer (score 1):

Normally Data Pipeline instantiates an Ec2Resource instance in the AWS cloud and runs the TaskRunner on this instance. The corresponding activity in the pipeline that is marked as 'runsOn' for the Ec2Resource is then run on this instance. For details refer to the documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-how-task-runner-dp-managed.html).

But any S3DistCp running on an EC2 instance will not have access to your on-premise HDFS. To have access to on-premise resources the corresponding activities will have to be executed by a TaskRunner running on an on-premise box. For details on how to set this up refer to the documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-how-task-runner-user-managed.html).

The TaskRunner is a java standalone application provided by AWS, that can be manually run on any self managed box. It connects to the data pipeline service over AWS API, to get metadata about tasks pending execution and then executes them on the same box where it is running.

In case of automated Ec2Resource provisioning, Data Pipeline instantiates the ec2 instance and runs this same TaskRunner on it, and all of it is transparent to us.